# extract a particular sequence from a file

Tags: regex, shell

I have a file which has space separator which are unequally spaced like,

```
john  0101 C1     Comp  
mayo 0120 D2     Comp
peter  0110 E1     IT
```

etc. I want to extract all values from file in a separate fields.
I tried using cut like,

```
cut -f1,2,3 -d " " line1
```

but only first name is getting extracted correctly not remaining. I think problem is with unequal spaces.please suggest me any solution on this.
Apologies if its a very easy question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is tr command present which can rescue you from this situation,

translate multiple occurences of single character into 1

```
echo $line | tr -s " " | cut -f1,2,3 -d " "
```

will do for you.
even Awk can also help

`awk '{print $1, $2, $3}'` (remaining fields also)

Comment: Why post a duplicate answer after 10 minutes?

Comment: yes I saw that too, but later when I clicked post.it was not done intensionally.

Comment: I use downvotes extremely rarely this is definitely not a case for downvote :)

Answer (score 8):

It is because `cut` doesn't work well with multiple occurrences of delimiters.

You can use awk instead:

```
awk '{print $1, $2, $3}' file
```

**Alternatively** you can use `tr -s ' '` to squeeze multiple spaces:

```
tr -s ' ' < file | cut -f1,2,3 -d " "
```

Comment: If it works out for you don't forget to mark the answer as accepted by  clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.